# Sponge with PRF instead of PRP

Tags: pseudo-random-function, permutation, pseudo-random-permutation, sponge

In most uses of Sponge mode of operations such as SHA3 and many of the round-2 candidates in the [NIST lightweight cryptography project](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/lightweight-cryptography/round-2-candidates), the underlaying primitive is a cryptographic permutation - that is, it's bijective.

For reasons of curiosity, I noticed that [a proposed Sponge-based PRNG](https://keccak.team/files/SpongePRNG.pdf) implement forward secrecy (back-tracing resistance) by truncating part of the permutation state to all-bits-zero (Section 4.3 of the linked paper).

This got me wonder, what if the permutation is one-way (e.g. $p(x) \oplus x$):

Q1: What are the security implications if SHA3 hash and XOF functions were built on top of Sponge-PRF?

Q2: If the proposed PRNG used PRF, how would the security proof break apart?

Q3: If sponge-based duplex AEADs used PRF, how would their security proof break apart?

Comment: One minor note: Sponges usually do not use keyed permutations (PRPs) but _public_ random permutations, so _technically_ PRF is not the correct model here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I sent a mail to the Keccak team asking about this, and I got a response from one of the authors (Joan Daemen to be specific).

According to him, we actually can instantiate Sponge functions and Duplex objects with a "transformation" in addition to a permutation, the latter of which is what we commonly do. As long as the underlaying (fixed-width) function is indistinguishable (computationally) from a random one.

So the real reason we don't usualy use a "transformation", is that - **It's not usually efficient**.

Quote from the mail response.

> The reason that the sponge construction is mostly instantiated with
>   permutations (Keccak, Xoodyak, Spongent, etc.) is that we - as a
>   cryptographic community - have a method to build efficient permutations
>   that seem to give rise to secure sponge functions but not to build
>   efficient transformations that do the same and the invertibility of the
>   permutation does not hurt as far as the indifferentiability and
>   indinguishability bounds are concerned. ...

This is true, the round functions in Feistel-network block ciphers such as DES and SM4 aren't optimal efficiency-wise, especially when compared to constructs such as ARX (add-rotate-xor such as that in ChaCha20), and bitwise-and-shift operations (such as those in Gimli, Keccak, NORX).

To conclude:

> ... We actually build a permutation
>   by iterating a simple round function that does mixing, nonlinearity and
>   shuffling. Sponges have been built with a transformation that is not a
>   permutation, like Gluon, but that was no great success in my opinion.

Comment: I don't see how is $p(x) \oplus x$ so inefficient. What has this to do with Feistel and ARX?